# Ubuntu 14.04 can't open Ntfs partition

Tags: dual-boot

I had install dual boot system on my laptop, ubuntu and win 10, first time I dual boot it ubuntu could freely access my drive C partition and other partition that windows could read (NTFS), but after a few times ubuntu can't read the partition, the eror window said I have to shutdown it since it read  the windows being use it when hibernate, i had completely shutdown the windows but still ubuntu file manager cant read it, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will apply to your situation but yesterday I had to format my USB drive to FAT / FAT32 for Ubuntu 14.04.3 to be able to read it - I had to create a formatted USB to then allow me to then create a Live USB stick.
I was on a Mac and used the Disk Utility to do it. Mac > Applications > Utilities > Disk Utility. So maybe could look at that possibility?>
Maia